# Uncaught Livewire: Directive already registered: [sortable]

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament

I am getting this error because I'm trying to install https://github.com/livewire/sortable  to my existing project that is using https://filamentphp.com/ (but just the [Forms](https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/forms) only)

In my `app.js`

```
import 'livewire-sortable'
```

Then I ran it to my browser.
But in my console, it says `Uncaught Livewire: Directive already registered: [sortable]`.

That's when I investigated it, Then I found `sortable.js` https://github.com/filamentphp/filament/blob/2.x/packages/forms/resources/js/sortable.js  on the `filament/forms`

```
import Sortable from 'sortablejs'

window.Sortable = Sortable

window.Livewire.directive('sortable', (el) => {
    el.sortable = Sortable.create(el, {
        draggable: '[wire\\:sortable\\.item]',
        handle: '[wire\\:sortable\\.handle]',
        dataIdAttr: 'wire:sortable.item',
    })
})

export default (Alpine) => {
    Alpine.directive('sortable', (el) => {
        el.sortable = Sortable.create(el, {
            draggable: '[x-sortable-item]',
            handle: '[x-sortable-handle]',
            dataIdAttr: 'x-sortable-item',
        })
    })
}
```

---

Now, is there a way I can change the directive into `livewireSortable` so that It will not affect the Filament Forms?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: @Milkmannetje yes. I just found out that Filament has `sortable` already. so no point in installing `livewire-sortable`

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same error, then I hard looked my code and found that I'm already

```
import 'livewire-sortable';
```

In the js/app.js file

And found that I also on app.blade.php

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/livewire/sortable@v0.x.x/dist/livewire-sortable.js"></script>
```

What I'm trying to say is that I think you have accidentally imported this whole script in two places (NPM (app.js file) and manually on CDN (app.blade.php after @livewireScripts).

Simply remove the duplicate, **leave the app.js import or just use CDN**.